# Umbraco: Upgrade from 7.4.2 to 7.5.3 broke parts of the backoffice

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Just upgraded a site from 7.4.2 to 7.5.3.

Copied over /bin, /umbraco and /umbraco_client; ran the installer, no reported problems.

A diff of the 7.5.3 ZIP compared to the upgraded site shows all identical with the exception of my site specific created views, assemblies, scripts etc.

The site works, as does content editing, document type editing and media and everything I've looked at in Developer.

However, template editing is broken; unstyled with no scripts running, as is stylesheets and users, user types

I have cleared the ClientDependency cache, changed the version, cleared all browsing history (also it is the same on another, previously unused browser) restarted the site, the app pool and IIS.

I don't really know what to do now!

Further info:

No errors in console.
No errors in Umbraco trace log.

Comment: Remember to merge all the config files as well (/config folder plus web.config).

Comment: Yup, done that.

Comment: When you edit the templates, what does the URL look like, does it look something like:

/umbraco/#/settings/framed/settings%252FViews%252FEditView.aspx%253FtreeType%253Dtemplates%2526templateID%253D1093

Or is it different?

Comment: I had to downgrade the site to get it working in the end because I needed it too urgently, but I'll get a mirror of it upgraded and add a bit more info, thanks for help!